# How to measure the information contained in a partition of set?

Tags: combinatorics, information-theory, set-partition

Is there any formal way to measure the information contained in a partition of set? Consider the case when $[n]$ is the full set. Intuitively, I would expect that the two extremal partitions $\{[n]\}$ and $\{\{i\}: i \in [n]\}$ contain the least and most information.

Comment: The _entropy_ of a partition is a good measure of the information contained. This is the sum of $-(|A|/n)\log_2(|A|/n)$ over all $A$ in the partition. The entropy of $\{[n]\}$ is zero, while the entropy of $\{\{i\}\mid i\in [n]\}$ attains the maximum value of $\log_2 n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $n_i$ be the number of elements of "class" $\# i$ with $\sum n_i=N$.

Let $$p_i=\frac{n_i}{N}.$$

In this way your initial set is probabilized.

Take now the classical measure of "disorder" called ["entropy"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in information theory:

$$E= -\sum p_i \log_2(p_i)$$

Comment: Any comment ? ....

Comment: Thanks! That's clear and insightful!